# Firefox addon: No update were found like message display in C#

Tags: c#

In the firefox addon update dialog, a message tip will be displayed which can be closed. I am looking for something like that in C#:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/static/CtrlMessageBar.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like this out-of-the-box.  You could develop something like this yourself, just use a panel which hosts other content and then you would move that content when you display the error panel (causing a resize, of course), or you could have it as a control that you drop down on any control and only make itself visible when you want it shown.